# Dont work objectsWithPredicate with operator "NOT IN"?

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate, realm

I need to take to get items from the array that are not in the database.I'm trying to make this predicate

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"!(id IN %@)", ids]; 
return[ProductModel objectsWithPredicate:predicate];
```

But it returns nil, but if you use a predicate without NOT, then everything works. This is work in coredata - Predicate returns the objects are not in the database. But doesn`t work in realm.

Comment: You are not using `NOT`, you are using `!`.

Comment: @rmaddy ! - equivalently "NOT". It is written in the documents of the Realm. And the NOT is not working too. https://realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/

Comment: If `NOT` isn't working either, then why did you accept the answer below when the only change was changing `!` to `NOT`?

Comment: @rmaddy The decision below, offers an array of filtering based on RLMResults and not vice versa.

Comment: I'm asking you why you accepted the answer since it doesn't solve your issue.

Comment: @rmaddy In fact, I originally did not think about it.

Comment: @nickheck Isn't it solved your problem as you are getting array of filtered items. Though its not telling why your predicate isn't working but its giving you an alternate way of achieving what you want. You must not roll back the accepted answer if its satisfying you.

Comment: @nickheck, would you mind sharing a larger piece of code that demonstrates the issue you're seeing? I threw together a test case locally and am not able to reproduce an issue, so we'll need more information to understand what's happening here. `NOT id IN %@`, `NOT(id IN %@)` and `!(id IN %@)` are all supported by Realm, and are all equivalent from  NSPredicate's point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (id IN %@)", ids]; 
NSArray *filtered  = [ids filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: Try again, I have updated the code. Please make sure your ids array must contain data. filtered array will contain list of filtered objects.

Comment: Thanks. its work, Just wanted to understand more why this predicate does not work with the realm objects.

Comment: This answer appears to be attempting to filter the list of IDs to contain only IDs not present in the list of IDs. That… doesn't make sense. It also can't work since presumably the objects in the `ids` array do not themselves have `id` properties.